# An <select> and <span> tag breaks into 2 lines inside <tr> tag when tr's width is smaller

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make a table that has a  field for each row and also a  for the mandatory indicator. When  is getting smaller, at a particular width, the  breaks into another line.

My expected behavior: the  width turns smaller related to the  until a  can't be smaller.  and  must always inline

Here is my code. It uses bootstrap. Please help me. If you need any further details, just tell me.

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;" class="form-inline">
    <span id="${grMD.sys_id}_mandatory_span" style="color:red; font-size: large;">*</span>
    <select class="form-control" name="${grMD.sys_id}_type" id="${grMD.sys_id}_type" onchange="updateSendTo(this, '${grMD.sys_id}')" required="true">
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Wrap them with `<span style="white-space: nowrap;">`. Putting that on a `td` doesn't work because table cells don't wrap at all.

Comment: It doesn't work, they still break into 2 line

Comment: I just wondered if there's any CSS properties that define the smallest width of the bootstrap "form-control" class. Breaking into new line is ok if the <select> is smaller, since <select> is still very big when it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below css that set `absolute` position of an `asterisk` sign.

```css
.form-inline.required span {
    padding-right: 15px;
    color:red;
    position: absolute;
}
.form-inline.required .form-control, .checkbox-inline {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="form-inline required">
            <span>*</span>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Hello World</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        
        <td class="form-inline required">
            <span>*</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Hello Universe" />
        </td>
        
        <td class="form-inline required">
            <span>*</span>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="" />
                Hello Planet
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let us know if any issue. Hopefully this helps someone !

Answer (score 1):

if you put the mandatory indicator in a narrow column by itself, the indicator will never break to a new line.

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;" class="form-inline">
    <span id="${grMD.sys_id}_mandatory_span" style="color:red; font-size: large;">*</span>
</td>
<td>
    <select class="form-control" name="${grMD.sys_id}_type" id="${grMD.sys_id}_type" onchange="updateSendTo(this, '${grMD.sys_id}')" required="true">
    </select>
</td>
```

Just a note, but, modern html best practices reserve the use of tables for tabular data, never layout. I might suggest you try [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) and read about [css flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Comment: I tried, but the rigth border of the new column should be hidden and for some reason the 'corner-right' property doesn't work (I work on a platform, I'm not sure if it supports all the CSS properties). I know about the bootstrap grid system but sadly, this is code of another one. I'm just fixing it so may be it's too much work to convert to bootstrap grid system =)))